# Set the path of dll files in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, automated-tests, tosca

[1]How to copy the path of dll files in visual studio.I have created a dll files in visual studio but I am unable to copying the path of dll files.Actually I have created a button on visual studio and I want to implement it on Tosca commander.but I am getting error message. Unable to copy file Access to the path is denied.

Comment: Gaurav, you question is not clear, can you please rephrase and give and example, you may get an answer to your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Try to describe what your actual goal is. Do you want to use a dll from one project in another? Or want to copy the files to some folder when they are built?